# Collection in C# Class Library

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple .dll class library C#. My file takes a values of my main program and create a html file with this values. Look at my code: (I am describing it so that you can check if I have a mistake)

```
public class MyClass1 { public void HTMLGen(int number, string name)
{
    var html1 = string.Format("<p>This is number: {0} and this is name: {1}</p>", number, name);

    var xDocument = new XDocument(
        new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
        new XElement("html",
            new XElement("head"),
            new XElement("body",
                    XElement.Parse(html1))));

    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "\t"
    };

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\Desktop\test.html", settings))
    {
        xDocument.WriteTo(writer);
    }
} }
```

Okay, this code works well. so I need add to collection. I create a new class-file in this .dll. This is my new class:

```
    public class Collection : IList {

    public int value_one { get; set; }
    public int value_two { get; set; }}
```

and I added this parameter to my class:

```
public class MyClass1 { public void HTMLGen(int number, string name, IList<Collection> collection)
```

so I create a new 'var html2' and I want to add this to XElement.Parse. This is my whole code:

```
public class MyClass1 { public void HTMLGen(int number, string name, IList<Collection> collection) {

var html1 = string.Format("<p>This is number: {0} and this is name: {1}</p>", number, name);
var html2 = string.Format("<p> /* value_one and value_two from Collection */ </p>");

var xDocument = new XDocument(
    new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
    new XElement("html",
        new XElement("head"),
        new XElement("body",
                XElement.Parse(html1), XElement.Parse(html2))));

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "\t"
};

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\Desktop\test.html", settings))
{
    xDocument.WriteTo(writer);
} } }
```

and please, look at my comment. I don't know, how Can I add this values of my collection to this var html2.

Comment: What are you trying to achive with the Collection class?

Comment: My 'var html2' must be dynamic because I want to use a foreach loop.

Comment: First of all, your Collection class wouldn't compile. Second, you are having an Ilist of an Ilist, and third, it is still unclear what you are trying to achive. Please, give us a more concrete example

Comment: I know only that I have to create a collection this way, I have to put in this var html2 values ​​from my collection and I must use foreach loop, because this 'var html2' must be generate dynamic. That's all and 
I'm trying to do it. (I'm learning)

Comment: You may think that you "know" this but you are almost certainly wrong. Either you are misunderstanding how to write good c# or more probably you are misunderstanding instructions you have received from somebody else. Go back to basics and tell us what your requirements are (eg being able to pass in a collection of integers) and we can try to help you achieve that. Creating an implementation of `IList` with two `int` properties is almost certainly *not* what you want to do.

Comment: `I know only that I have to create a collection this way` Tell us how you know this. Did someone tell you to? Why aren't you using the built in collections (`List<T>` etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't understand why you would need to create a class named Collection with two integers.  You can either use a int Array or list.  Or may be a structure would be the best thing to use if you have not just int but other datatypes.

Lets suppose you need that class, then why should it inherit IList?  I don't see any usage of it at all.

Anyway, just to answer your question:

```
var html2 = string.Format("<p> /* {0} and {1} from Collection */ </p>", collection.value_one, collection.value_two);
```

Or, if you have different types for your values, just convert it to string to be safe.

```
var html2 = string.Format("<p> /* {0} and {1} from Collection */ </p>", collection.value_one.ToString(), collection.value_two.ToString());
```

Comment: `String.Format` doesn't require you to call `ToString` on the variables you are passing in - it does it automatically so your two code snippets actually do the same thing. I'm not sure what safety you think the second one is giving you...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to achive this?

```
public class MyClass1 
{ 

    public void HTMLGen(int number, string name,  IList<int> collection) 
    {
        var html1 = string.Format("<p>This is number: {0} and this is name: {1}</p>", number, name);
        string html2 = "";

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            html2 += item + " ";
        }

        html2 = "<p>" + html2 + "</p>";
        //The rest of the code
    }
}
```

usage:

```
MyClass1 myClass1 = new MyClass1();
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 4, 3, 21, 123, 6 };
myClass1.HTMLGen(10, "name", numbers);
```

Comment: I don't understand. html2 must generate a my html code. Why u wrote a " " ?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot it's a HTML string.. :P Just surround it with p tags like so:  
html2 = "<p>" + html2 + "</p>"

Comment: could you edit your code in a post? it will help me a lot.

Comment: Ok, nice but I have a this: var html2 = string.Format("<p> This is value one: {0} and this is value two: {1}</p>", collecton.value_one, collection.value_two);

And I want to generate this code dynamically in my foreach loop. will it work with your code? 
If so, will you show me exactly on this code?

Comment: OMFG. Don't take me wrong, but please I am not a code generator. I have shown you what you asked for, you could try to think of the rest..

FYI: you can do it, I would use a counter variable, and add it's value like so: html2 += (n + 1).ToString() + "th item: " + item + " ";

Comment: Okay, thanks man. I'm very sorry, but I'm learning programming and 
I'm trying to understand.

Comment: It's just, you will be much better at programming if you try to figure it out for yourself. Even if you don't know what you are doing, the trying itself will teach you a hull bunch more than any teacher or forum could.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) to avoid long String.Format method usage like below.

```
var html1 = $"<p>This is number: {number} and this is name: {name}</p>");
var html2 = $"<p> This is first value: {collection[0]} and this is second value: {collection[1]}</p>";
```